# How can I adapt the awk code if I have a .gz file?

Tags: awk, gzip

I have the code

```
awk '
NR == FNR {
   chromosome[$1];
   start[$1] = $2;
   end[$1] = $3;
   next
}
$1 in start && $2 >= start[$1] && $2 <= end[$1]
' gene_positions.txt GWAS_results.txt > lookup_output.txt
```

Basically what the code is doing: the AWK script is filtering and extracting records from GWAS_results.txt based on the positions of genes defined in gene_positions.txt, capturing entries that fall within specific genomic ranges for certain chromosomes.

My file is in the format **GWAS_results.txt.gz**, how can I change the code so it handles the gzipped format. Is it better to gunzip the file before running the above code. I notice when I gunzip GWAS_results.txt.gz. - it runs forever forcing me to close the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to `gzip` the file before, use `zcat` to read the file and the pipe its contents over standard input of Awk using the dash argument

```bash
zcat GWAS_results.txt.gz |
awk 'NR == FNR { chromosome[$1]; start[$1] = $2; end[$1] = $3; next } 
     $1 in start && $2 >= start[$1] && $2 <= end[$1]' gene_positions.txt - > lookup_output.txt
```

---

Also `gzip` needs to be invoked with `-d` to specify decompression of files.